# Entity Framework Miss Update

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Sometimes the entity is not updated within scope, but inserts are committed.
I'm thinking that this problem is due to the isolation level, added to the number of queries in the registry. I also think that it might be the order in which things are effective in the db, since the endpoint calls that imply changing the entity happen very quickly, even if in the correct order. I don't know...

The code is like:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
     var db = new Context().Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;")

     var student= db.Students.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == 1);

     var schoolName = "TestSchool";

     db.School.Insert(new School{ Name = schoolName }); // IT ALWAYS WORKS

     student.School = schoolName; //SOMETIMES THIS CHANGE DOESN'T WORK

     db.Save();

     scope.Complete();
}
```

Any help?

It's only occur with mass data, making tests difficult

Comment: What is the type of `student.School`?

Comment: It's just an example, in the real case it's INT. Status = 1.

Comment: Have you changed the default tracking / no tracking behaviour? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#no-tracking-queries

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is query the school first, then assign the result to `student.School`

Something like this:

```cs
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
     var db = new Context().Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;")

     var student= db.Students.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == 1);

     var schoolName = "TestSchool";

     db.School.Insert(new School{ Name = schoolName }); // IT ALWAYS WORKS

     // Query new school here
     var newSchool = db.School.SingleOrDefault(x => x.SchoolName = schoolName);
     // Assign the result to student's School property
     student.School = newSchool;

     db.Save();

     scope.Complete();
}
```

This way, Entity Framework would be able to "track" the changes and generate the correct SQL to update the database